# Nodejs/ Nginx server(AWS)/ Mysql/ insert 502 Bad Gateway error

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx

When I try to insert some text with Mysql, AWS ElasticBeanstalk Nginx server,

It sometimes come out the error message that 502 Bad Gateway.

Only insert case is error(select, update, delete are working very well.)

If I try to insert in localhost, It's working very well.

```html
<form action="/finance" method="post">
 <div class="input-field col l12">
  <input name="consult_name" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="send"> 
 </div>
</form>
```

```js
router.post('/finance', function(req, res, next) {
 var consult_name = req.body.consult_name;
 console.log(consult_name);
 
 
 var sets = {consult_name : consult_name};
 
 mysql.insert('insert into cider.cid_finance set ?', sets,  function (err, data){

 res.redirect('/finance');
 });
});
```

```html
2016/08/30 22:04:24 [error] 29838#0: *52 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 115.95.162.173, server: , request: "POST /finance HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/finance", host: "cidermics.com", referrer: "http://cidermics.com/finance"
2016/08/30 22:04:24 [error] 29838#0: *52 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 115.95.162.173, server: , request: "POST /finance HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/finance", host: "cidermics.com", referrer: "http://cidermics.com/finance"
```

AWS ElasticBeanstalk error log

```html
/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:48:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:83:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:73:12)
    at Protocol.write (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:98:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
```

Comment: Which npm mysql package are you using?

Comment: "_from": "felixge/node-mysql",
  "_id": "mysql@2.10.2",

Comment: I can't recognize. Is it this https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql.
It seems Parser Error.
Try inserting as :
mysql.insert('insert into cider.cid_finance set  = '+consult_name,  function (err, data){

 res.redirect('/finance');
 });

Comment: Have a look at this:
https://thebittheories.com/my-complicated-relationship-with-js-8cea2afa5d44

This article shows ways to implement nodejs app on aws ubuntu ec2 instance. 

Follow The Bit Theories for more computer science related reads. :)

Comment: It doesn't work... actually Insert is working by chance of 80%

Answer (score 0):

You're sql syntax is wrong. The error message clearly states that the mysql syntax is where the problem is.

Try this:

```
mysql.insert('insert into cider.cid_finance set consult_name = ?', consult_name,  function (err, data){
```

Comment: It doesn't work... actually Insert is working by chance of 80%

Comment: Post the error you're getting now... also try wrapping consult_name in an array [consult_name], and take a look at the docs... https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries